# how to display Youtube Video in android VideoView?

Tags: android

I am working android application.How can i play youtube in android videoview.help me........

Thanks............

Comment: This is not particularly easy. This should help, but it does not work 100% of the time. http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/

Answer (score 4):

You should read through the [YouTube APIs and Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) documentation, specifically about [Feeds and Entries](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Understanding_Video_Entries). From the feed you should be able to parse the actual .3gp video stream URL, which you can then play back using the standard MediaPlayer with a VideoView.