# play video in android

Tags: php, android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to play youtube video . I am using  the following code

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));
```

It is works.It play the video from youtube site.But I want to play a video in my layout

Comment: Buddy.. Just put more efforts in search... Google doesn't charge it.. Anyway Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556802/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864178/how-to-display-youtube-video-in-android-videoview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007695/streaming-youtube-videos

Comment: have a look at my [answer][1] ,it will solve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12158743/1206201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to embed the YouTube video in a `WebView` using the `<iframe>` tag, then put that `WebView` inside a parent layout, such as `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`. Here's a similar question to yours with an accepted answer, plus some sample code on how to do it: [Android video embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674469/android-video-embedding)